# Which Trello API Action occurs when someone moves a card between boards?

Tags: trello

I am trying to get Card history from a series of Boards within my Organization. I can get the actions when a card is moved between lists, but which action records when the card is moved between boards. I have stepped though getting the actions for Boards, Lists and Cards and have not seen any that indicate when a card was moved between boards.

Answer (score 2):

It's called moveCardToBoard.  You can get it from the actions associated with a board (https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-actions) or the actions associated with a card (https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions); I don't think it's in the actions associated with the list.

Comment: It's now `updateCard` because you're updating the `idList` attribute on the card itself.

Comment: Like @mattblessed says it's `updateCard` now. I'm also getting the following
`action.display.translationKey='action_move_card_from_list_to_list'`, `action.data.listAfter` and `action.data.listBefore` keys